# How to capture the return value from controller action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

I am using uploadify to upload .csv files on my ASP.NET MVC app. From the controller action I return a JSON with a couple of values like this:

```
return Json(new { success = false, message = result.Message });
```

The following is the uploadify code:

```
$("#email").uploadify(
                    {
                    'uploader': '/js/component/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                    'script': '/email/UploadEmail',
                    'cancelImg': '/js/component/uploadify/cancel.png',
                    'fileExt': '*.csv',
                    'fileDesc': '*.csv',
                    'auto': true,
                    'multi': false,
                    'buttonText': 'Upload...',

                        'onComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data)
                            {

                                alert(jQuery.parseJSON(response));
                                alert(jQuery.parseJSON(response.message));
                                var filename = fileObj.name;
                                $('#emailSuppressionFile').append('<input id="' + queueID + '" type="hidden" name="files[' + queueID + ']" value="' + filename + '" />');                                   
}                                
                    });
```

I am trying to read the "message" that I returned from the controller action but can't figure out how. Please see the alerts above.The first alert returns: [object Object] and the second return null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
onComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    alert(json.message);
},
```

Also don't put quotes around the event name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that, but result still returns null.

Comment: What's the value of `response.responseText`?

Comment: response.responseText is undefined and result then calculates to null.

Comment: What about the `response` variable? What does it contain?

Comment: response evaluates to {"success":false,"message":"Email failed to upload"}

Comment: What about `alert(jQuery.parseJSON(response).message);`? This should work. I have updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

In old version of Uploadify onComplete event, use to provide response back from Controller. 
But, in latest version you need to use onUploadSuccess event, like this,

```
   'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
         alert('The file ' + file.name + ' was successfully uploaded with a response of ' + response + ':' + data);
    }
```